# Displaying a field associated with a max date value record

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working on an MS Access database and have been trying to get an unbound field on a main navigation form to display the *LastUserChange* that is associated with the record that was last updated.

I have used `DMax()` to identify the record that was most recently updated, but I can't seem to get the user ID associated with that record to display. I have a field in the table with the date timestamp that stores the user ID with it, so the data is saved in the same table. The code that I have been working on is as follows:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT tblstatusupdate.LastUserChange" & _
         "FROM tblstatusupdate " & _
         "WHERE tblstatusupdate.LastChangeDate = DMax("LastChangeDate", "tblStatusUpdate")"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

Me.LastUpdateBy = strSQL
End Sub
```

The code that I used to get the date of the most recently updated record is:

```vb
= DMax("LastChangeDate", "tblStatusUpdate")
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: How does that VBA code compile? Quotes are not properly set in *strSQL*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a mistake of new users in MS Access, `DoCmd.RunSQL` is reserved for action queries (i.e., `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `ALTER`, `CREATE`) and not `SELECT` queries that return a resultset.

However, for your needs consider running nested domain functions in VBA without any SQL calls. `DLookUp` looks up user with the criteria that its change date matches the max value of table using `Dmax`. Date literals must be enclosed with `#` characters and not quotes.

```vb
Me.LastUpdatedBy = DLookUp("LastUserChange", "tblStatusUpdate", "LastChangeDate = #" _
                            & DMax("LastChangeDate", "tblStatusUpdate") & "#")
```

Comment: It's so simple! Thank you so much! I literally worked on this with 3 other people yesterday to no avail.This works perfectly!

Comment: Excellent! That's what StackOverflow is here for! Glad to help.